# What's the probability of losing a coin tossing gambling with a wealthy man?

Tags: probability

Imagine you have $k$ dollars in your pocket and you are gambling with a wealthy man (with infinitely much money). The rule is repeatedly tossing a coin and you win $\$1$ if it's a head, otherwise you lose $\$1$. Now, what's the probability that you get broke eventually?

Comment: [Gambler's Ruin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Comment: The probability is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question in stochastic processes known as Gambler's ruin problem.

the answer is :If coin is fair,gambler **will** go broke with probability $1$.

Also it should be noted that if the coin is biased,i.e, probability of gambler winning is greater that $0.5$, then there is strictly positive probabilty that Gambler is **never** broke.

Comment: Which is 1-((1-p)/p)^g where g is Gambler's initial fortune and p>.5 is the probability that Gambler wins a single toss.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $1$. This is the [gambler’s ruin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin), and see also [one-dimensional random walks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk).